# VB.NET FromEventPattern

Tags: vb.net, observablecollection, system.reactive, c#-to-vb.net

I'm new to Reactive Extension and unfortunately we use VB.NET so I'm having some trouble converting C# examples to VB.NET.
I'm trying to create a simple ObservableCollection(of String) and subscribe to it.  Anytime a string is added to the collection, I want to write it out to the console.
I'm trying to translate this example to VB.NET and am having trouble.

```
var x = Observable.FromEventPattern<NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>(
    handler => (sender, e) => handler(sender, e),
    handler => theList.CollectionChanged += handler,
    handler => theList.CollectionChanged -= handler);
}
```

I've gotten this far, but can't get it to work, I'm sure it's simple, but I'm a newbie.

```
Dim changes = Observable.FromEventPattern(Of System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs) _
(Function(handler) Function(sender, args) handler(sender, args), _
Function(handler) AddHandler theList.CollectionChanged, AddressOf handler, _
Function(handler) RemoveHandler theList.CollectionChanged, AddressOf handler)
```

Thanks to @Gideon Engelberth for helping me remove the unneeded `AddressOf`
This compiled fine:

```
Dim changes = Observable.FromEventPattern(Of 
              System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler, _
              NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs) _
              (Function(handler) Sub(sender, args) handler(sender, args), _
              Sub(handler) AddHandler theList.CollectionChanged, handler, _
              Sub(handler) RemoveHandler theList.CollectionChanged, handler)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per request, I usually do like so:

```
Dim c As New ObservableCollection(Of String)
Dim obs = Observable.FromEventPattern(Of NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler, 
                                         NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)(
                Sub(h) AddHandler c.CollectionChanged, h,
                Sub(h) RemoveHandler c.CollectionChanged, h)
```

Since `h` is already a delegate variable, you do not need the AddressOf operator.

Answer (score 0):

The `AddHandler` and `RemoveHandler` calls do not return a value, so you can not use them with `Function`.  Try using `Sub` instead for the last two arguments.

```
Dim changes = Observable.FromEventPattern(Of System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs) _
(Function(handler) Function(sender, args) handler(sender, args), _
Sub(handler) AddHandler theList.CollectionChanged, AddressOf handler, _
Sub(handler) RemoveHandler theList.CollectionChanged, AddressOf handler)
```

Comment: The first argument should be `Function(handler) Sub(sender, args) ...`. An event handler does not return a value.  Though I have never used this overload, I usually use the one taking only the add/remove handler methods.

Comment: @GideonEngelberth, I made this change and it got rid of my first compile error.  However, I'm still getting the compile error of _'AddressOf' operand must be the name of a method (without parentheses)_ on the Add\Remove Handler lines `AddressOf handler`.  Could you create your own answer with the overload you use as an example?  Thank you!